# My wordpress website showing 2 titles in source code how can i fix this issue

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

[image]

My WordPress website shows 2 titles in the source code how can I fix this issue

Comment: Make sure your theme's `header.php` doesn't have a `wp_title()` call within the `<head></head>` section.

Comment: can you please share example code

Comment: so i can check my header file

Comment: The folder containing your currently active theme. Should be in `/wp-content/themes/`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it is because of Yoast SEO plugin.

Check here maybe it can solve your problem : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/still-have-2-titles-with-yoast-14-1/